# Can't use echo option within shell script file

Tags: shell-script, echo, options

My sh is bash. I need a percentile progress indicator for my 0~9999 'for' loop... So I use this lines within the loop, but the output is very strange.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i percentile
for((i=0;i<=9999;i++))
do
        percentile=($i+1)%100
        if [ "$percentile" == 0 ];then
                echo -ne $((($i+1)/100))\%\r
        fi
done
echo -n '\n'
```

What I want to see is it outputs '1%' and then replace this line with '2%' and '3%' ... but not '1%', '2%', '3%', ... line by line.

After execute this .sh file, what displayed on the terminal is

```
-ne 1%r
-ne 2%r
-ne 3%r
-ne 4%r
-ne 5%r
-ne 6%r
-ne 7%r
-ne 8%r
-ne 9%r
-ne 10%r
...
```

The bash just didn't recognize the '-ne' option and the escaped '\r' for 'echo' command, what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: And your `sh` is?

Comment: Your script works fine for me. Could be different shells. What about using `printf` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `echo`, then try with quoted return, ie `'\r'`, not just `\r`. The whole line is then:

```
echo -ne $((($i+1)/100))\%'\r'
```

And take a look at [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're using `bash` because both the `-n` and `-e` flags are usually understood by `bash`'s `echo` utility.

Make sure that you run the script by either explicitly specifying `bash` as the interpreter,

```
$ bash ./script.sh
```

or by making it executable and running it,

```
$ chmod +x ./script.sh
$ ./script.sh
```

Your arithmetic operations in the script are also wrong (when calculating `percentile`).  `bash` performs arithmetic substitutions in `$(( ... ))` and arithmetic evaluation in `(( ... ))`.

Here's an alternative implementation:

```
iter=70500

for(( i = 1; i <= iter; i++ )); do
    if ! (( i % (iter/100) )); then
        printf '\r%d%%' "$(( (100*i)/iter ))"
    fi
done

echo
```